# Error using Framework7 and service.js for hosting in the local host

Tags: node.js, npm, html-framework-7

when i clicked the npm run service. This error is what i am getting
I have used the same app in the following link:
https://github.com/valnub/f7-node-autocomplete-search-demo

```
framework7-react-app-template@3.0.0 service C:\Users\Tallam Tharun Sai\auto-complete
PORT=3001 nodemon service/service.js

'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! framework7-react-app-template@3.0.0 service: `PORT=3001 nodemon service/service.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the framework7-react-app-template@3.0.0 service script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tallam Tharun Sai\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-10T18_16_54_175Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this is.

I have deleted the Package.json and Node modules from the project and again followed the steps to install the npm as (npm install).

Then I have the installed my npm app successfully.